# IBM Bluemix PHP Application create startup file

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I have made a PHP application within IBM Bluemix.
Is it possible to place code somewhere within the application so that it always runs when the you deploy your code?
This is because I want to initialize some files with data, when the instance is ready for use.

Greetings,

Arjan Kroon

Comment: Probably, but depends on what you mean by "always runs when the you deploy your code". When your application is built and launched on Bluemix, it will always be available when a request is made for the file. Please clarify what you mean, providing examples when possible.

Comment: On the php instance I use a sqllite3 database.  From this database there will be a backup on an external system.  
Now when new code for the instances is deployed, I want to copy the backupped database from the external system to the php instance.

Answer (score 3):

At the root of your project, create a `composer.json`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "COMMAND GOES HERE"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can either enter a command or call a PHP class.

Example:[Running DreamFactory 2.0 on BlueMix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779622/running-dreamfactory-2-0-on-bluemix)

Doc: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names

However, having your database within your php instance is not good practice. If your php instance crashes, you can lose your data. If you scale to multiple instances, how can you keep your databases in sync?

You should consider using a database that sits outside of your php instance. Pick from one of the databases from the Bluemix catalog.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to override the buildpack's start command and provide your own via the cf push `-s` option. It could be something like `-s command1 && command2` where command1 is the extra work you want to do and command2 starts the web app.